# Kotlin multi platform flow block convert to custom wrapper flow use for ios

Tags: java, kotlin, graphql, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a kotlin multi platform project which contains apollo graphql api

**in this project i have BaseRepository Class and in this class there is a method to execute query or mutations**

```
suspend fun <D : Query.Data> executeQuery(query: Query<D>): ApolloResponse<D> {
        val response = getApolloClient().query(query).execute()

        checkOperation(response)

        return response
    }

    suspend fun <D : Mutation.Data> executeMutation(mutation: Mutation<D>): ApolloResponse<D> {
        val response = getApolloClient().mutation(mutation).execute()

        checkOperation(response)

        return response
    }
```

**For example i want to use this method in Some repository like this**

```
class HelpRepository : BaseRepository() {

    fun test(request: AddFeedBackRequest) = flow {

        val feedBackType = if (request.type == AddFeedBackType.Bug) {
            FeedbackType.BUG
        } else {
            FeedbackType.FEEDBACK
        }

        val input = AddFeedbackInput(request.note, Optional.presentIfNotNull(feedBackType))

        emit(true)

        val mutation = AddFeedbackMutation(input)

        val response = executeMutation(mutation)

        emit(false)

    }
}
```

when i add the flow scope i shouldn't be had to convert this method to a suspend function

i dont want to use suspend function because of ios application. When i use suspend function its convert "Kotlinx_coroutines_coreFlowCollector" in xcode

so i found a wrapper function like this

```
fun <T> Flow<T>.asCommonFlow(): CommonFlow<T> = CommonFlow(this)
class CommonFlow<T>(private val origin: Flow<T>) : Flow<T> by origin {
    fun listen(block: (T) -> Unit): Closeable {
        val job = Job()

        onEach {
            block(it)
        }.launchIn(CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + job))

        return object : Closeable {
            override fun close() {
                job.cancel()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**when i use this wrapper with single variable it works exactly what i want in xcode.**

but in functions i couldn't find a proper way to do this

**i need a wrapper like**

```
= commonFlow {
}

instead of this

= flow {
}
```

**to use this method as a commonFlow wrapper**

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have pretty much the same thing in one of our projects. We have a extension function that converts the regular flow to a "common" flow so it can be used in both Android and iOS.

You can created flow like always, and wrap it at the end.

```
fun <T> Flow<T>.wrap(): CommonFlow<T> = CommonFlow(this)

class HelpRepository : BaseRepository() {

fun test(request: AddFeedBackRequest) = flow {

    val feedBackType = if (request.type == AddFeedBackType.Bug) {
        FeedbackType.BUG
    } else {
        FeedbackType.FEEDBACK
    }

    val input = AddFeedbackInput(request.note, Optional.presentIfNotNull(feedBackType))

    emit(true)

    val mutation = AddFeedbackMutation(input)

    val response = executeMutation(mutation)

    emit(false)

}
}.wrap()
```

Comment: thanks for that now i can use exactly what i want but i got this error when i run on ios app.

"There is no event loop. Use runBlocking { ... } to start one"

so i found the solution on this link
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-4149/Ktor-app-with-KotlinNative-fails-with-There-is-no-event-loop-Use-runBlocking-to-start-one

when i add kotlin.native.binary.memoryModel=experimental to the gradle.properties it works.

I wonder that you solved this problem with this solution or another solution ?

Comment: If possible, use the memory model. This provides all needed functionality for multithreading and object sharing. Else you will need to implement your own functionality to freeze. I don't know how you use it in the iOS app, so it makes it a bit difficult to provide another solution. Check [this](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2021/08/try-the-new-kotlin-native-memory-manager-development-preview/) to see what the memory model is